# Delete slide in swiperjs, if slide display css equals to none

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Hi there working on project in CMS "bitrix" with using swiperjs.
I have page with the slider of support products for user region
In this project user can choose his location and based on his location he can see active support products for his region.

I'm using display='none' css style to hide all products except his region porducts. Im trying to delete from slider slides with display='none' css style.

My js knowledge is awful.
So i need to delete(hide) slides if its css display in 'none'.

Tried swiper.removeSlide function but it's not working. Will be very happy if anyone could help. Here is my code for now

```
    <div class="d-flex blog-slider">
        <div class="blog-slider__wrp swiper-wrapper">

            <? foreach ($arElementMain as $arElement): ?>
                <?
                $this->AddEditAction($arElement['ID'], $arElement['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
                $this->AddDeleteAction($arElement['ID'], $arElement['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCS_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
                ?>



                <?if($arElement['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['LINK']['VALUE']) $link = $arElement['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['LINK']['VALUE']; else $link = $arElement["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"];
                ?>


                <? $detail = $arElement["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>
                <?$i=0;foreach($arElement["PROPERTIES"]["REGION2"]["VALUE"] as $_SESSION["region"]):?>

                    <?if($_SESSION["region"]==$_SESSION["flag"])  $display = 'block'; else $display = 'none'?>


                    <div class="d-flex blog-slider__item swiper-slide" style="display:<?= $display; ?>;">
                        <div class="blog-slider__img">
                            <img src="<?= $arElement["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"] ?>" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class=" blog-slider__content">
                            <div class="blog-slider__title"><?echo $arElement["NAME"]?></div>
                            <div class="blog-slider__text"><?= $arElement["PREVIEW_TEXT"] ?> </div>
                            <div class="d-flex mb-3">

                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center mr-4">
                                    <div class="text-muted">Процентная ставка<br><p class="detail"><?echo $arElement['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['PERCENT']['DISPLAY_VALUE']; ?></p></div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center ">
                                    <div class="text-muted">Срок<br><p class="detail"><?echo $arElement['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['DMAIN']['DISPLAY_VALUE']; ?></p></div>

                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-group mt-4">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary mr-4 px-3 py-2" href="<?=$detail?>" role="button">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>




                <?endforeach;?>
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-slider__pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <? if ($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]): ?>
            <br/><?= $arResult["NAV_STRING"] ?>
        <? endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js code

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.blog-slider', {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        effect: 'fade',
        loop: true,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        mousewheel: {
            invert: false,
        },
        // autoHeight: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.blog-slider__pagination',
            clickable: true,
        }
    });


    $('.swiper-slide').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display')=='none') {
            swiper.removeSlide($(this));
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you render it when you don't want it? Just don't echo it out in php when it shouldn't be displayed anyways.